# Gtk.PrintOperation.run () not responding

Tags: python-3.x, printing, gtk3

I am trying to use the following script to print documents.  The problem is that
nothing happens.  The word "execute" is printed and when I click on the dialog
CANCEL button the response is as expected.  The PREVIEW and PRINT buttons cause
the dialog to exit but no result is printed.  The three callback methods are
stubbed out with each printing its name, none of which are displayed.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with python 3.6.7.

```
import gi
gi.require_version ('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib, Gdk

def PrintManager (self):
    ps = Gtk.PrintSettings.new ()
    po = Gtk.PrintOperation.new ()
    po.set_print_settings (ps)
    po.set_n_pages (1)

    po.connect ("begin_print", self.BeginPrint, self.PrintList)
    po.connect ("draw_page", self.DrawPage, self.PrintList)
    po.connect ("end_print", self.EndPrint, self.PrintList)

    print ("execute")                                                     #x
    result = po.run (Gtk.PrintOperationAction.PRINT_DIALOG, const.internal["parent"])
    print (result)                                                        #x

    if result == Gtk.PrintOperationResult.APPLY:
       ps = op.get_print_settings ()

    elif result == Gtk.PrintOperationResult.ERROR:
       dialog = Gtk.MessageDialog.new (Gtk.DialogFlags.DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
          Gtk.MessageType.ERROR, Gtk.ButtonsType.CLOSE, const.printError)
       dialog.run ()
       dialog.destroy ()


def BeginPrint (self, po, ctx, data):
    print ("{}.BeginPrint ()".format (__name__)) 


def DrawPage (self, po, ctx, cnt, data):
    print ("{}.DrawPage ({})".format (__name__, cnt))


def EndPrint (self, po, ctx, data):
    print ("{}.EndPrint ()".format (__name__))
```

Comment: Please use a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't test your code because it is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your program(most likely that `const` thing), because this does work as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


class GUI:
    def __init__(self):

        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        button = Gtk.Button(label = "print op")
        button.connect("clicked", self.button_clicked )
        self.window.add(button)
        self.window.set_size_request(400, 400)
        self.window.show_all()

    def button_clicked (self, button):
        ps = Gtk.PrintSettings.new ()
        po = Gtk.PrintOperation.new ()
        po.set_print_settings (ps)
        po.set_n_pages (1)
        self.PrintList = []
        po.connect ("begin_print", self.BeginPrint, self.PrintList)
        po.connect ("draw_page", self.DrawPage, self.PrintList)
        po.connect ("end_print", self.EndPrint, self.PrintList)

        print ("execute")                                                     #x
        result = po.run (Gtk.PrintOperationAction.PRINT_DIALOG, self.window)
        print (result)                                                        #x

        if result == Gtk.PrintOperationResult.APPLY:
            ps = po.get_print_settings ()

        elif result == Gtk.PrintOperationResult.ERROR:
            dialog = Gtk.MessageDialog.new (Gtk.DialogFlags.DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
                Gtk.MessageType.ERROR, Gtk.ButtonsType.CLOSE, po.printError)
            dialog.run ()
            dialog.destroy ()


    def BeginPrint (self, po, ctx, data):
        print ("{}.BeginPrint ()".format (__name__)) 


    def DrawPage (self, po, ctx, cnt, data):
        print ("{}.DrawPage ({})".format (__name__, cnt))


    def EndPrint (self, po, ctx, data):
        print ("{}.EndPrint ()".format (__name__))

    def on_window_destroy(self, window):
        Gtk.main_quit()

app = GUI()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try.